# Django password reset. Not sending mail

Tags: django, email, django-forms, django-authentication

I'm trying to get the django password reset working but the reset email does not get sent.

I know my email is properly configured because the following works both in the shell and in one of my views (I'm using it to get support email to myself).

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.',
          'admin@mydomain.com',['me@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

I can get to my reset password view (**password/reset/**) and after I give it my email it correctly redirects me to **password/reset/done/** but it doesn't sends the email.

Here's my `urls.py`:

```
(r'^password/reset/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset'),
(r'^password/reset/done/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
(r'^password/reset/confirm/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
(r'^password/reset/complete/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
(r'^password/change/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_change'),
(r'^password/change/done/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done'),
```

Here's my `password_reset_form.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/style_login.css" />
    <title>Información de acceso requerida</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Recuperar password</h1>
        <p>Utilice este formulario cuando desee recuperar el password para su usuario.</p>
        {% if form.errors %}
        <p>No hay un usuario registrado con ese correo electronico.</p>
        {% endif %}
        <form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input class="login" type="submit" value="Recuperar" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please turn your comment into a real answer below. You can mark it as accepted after two days. That will make the question go away from the Unanswered Questions tab.

Comment: Cool, I'm new to the community and that kind of tips are really helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome, thanks a lot for coming back and helping us clean up!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I should have mention I'm using hostgator as my provider. So this is my settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST      = 'my-domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my cpanel password'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my cpanel user'
EMAIL_PORT      = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS   = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  = 'webmaster@my-host.com'
SERVER_EMAIL    = 'root@my-domain.com'
```

The above settings work!

Comment: I had the same issue, the missing value is DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL. If that is not set, the email won't send.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I created the users using `create_user()`. My idea was to create a bunch of accounts and then tell people they could go to the password reset form to set their password. I think it sucks if you need to tell them 'Use password "welcome123" and then don't forget to modify your password' or such.

I found out if I did not pass `Password='foo'` or also if I passed `Password=None` to `create_user()` password resets are *not sent*. This is because Django sometimes uses an empty password to know that it does not need to authenticate locally, but rather use LDAP or such.

So now I do this:

```
User.objects.create_user(
  user_name,
  email=user_email,
  password=os.urandom(32),
)
```

And I can direct people to use the password reset function for their new accounts. I think it would be awesome if I had an option in create_user to automatically send emails for account activation to users, though!

Comment: Thanks, I have been pulling out my hair for hours trying to figure this out.

Btw, there is
`password = User.objects.make_random_password()`

Comment: Thanks! FYI neither os.urandom() or make_random_password() worked for me, I used:

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
password = make_password(User.objects.make_random_password())

Comment: Anyone thinking or doing this should stop IMMEDIAGTELY and create custom forms to allow users to signup.  if you want to do stuff like admin approval, email varification, or the like... use http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a default from address e.g:

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  = 'info@mymail.com'

I see now it is in the comments but will add it here in case anyone misses them too.